# Texture alpha channel does not work in opengl

Tags: opengl, textures, alpha

How can I use image with alpha channel? Since now i have tried this:

```
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D,
             0,
             GL_RGBA,
             width, height,
             0,      
             GL_BGRA,
             GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,
             bits);
```

with this opengl command:

```
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texgun5);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glColor3f(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
glEnable (GL_BLEND);
glBlendFunc (GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
        glTexCoord2f(0.0, 0.0);
        glVertex3f(gun5[0], gun5[1], gun5[2]);
        glTexCoord2f(1.0, 0.0);
        glVertex3f(gun5[3], gun5[4], gun5[5]);
        glTexCoord2f(1.0, 1.0);
        glVertex3f(gun5[6], gun5[7], gun5[8]);
        glTexCoord2f(0.0, 1.0);
        glVertex3f(gun5[9], gun5[10], gun5[11]);
    glEnd();
glDisable(GL_BLEND);
```

I'm using a png image loaded with Freeimage, but the trasparent pixel are all black, where is the error?

Comment: You will have to call glEnable(GL_ALPHA); somewhere during your initialization.

Comment: Your code looks absolutely fine. The error must be elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

I think you forgot to specify blending in the texture environment.  Insert this right after your glTexParameteri calls:

```
glTexEnvi(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_DECAL);
```

Comment: nope, it has a weird behaviour, it invert the color of all textures

Comment: @PhantomFav : Looking at the online docs, looks like it should be GL_DECAL rather than GL_BLEND.  Changed my answer to reflect.

Comment: thanks for your help but now the trasparent pixels are white instead of black.

Answer (score 1):

Textures are loaded properly, but not displayed so. Use `glTexEnvi(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_MODULATE);` instead of `glTexEnvi(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_DECAL);`
if that isnt enough, try `glDepthMask(GL_FALSE);` to see if you have at least alpha values. If thats not enough, try

```
glEnable( GL_ALPHA_TEST );
glAlphaFunc( GL_NOTEQUAL, 0.0 );
```

in your init function

Answer (score 0):

Transparent Pixels are white because color of you specified is white. According to `GL_DECAL` reference with `RGBA` format the formula which is being applied here is `Cp * (1- As) + Cs*As`, Now when your texture is completely transparent your `As` will become `0` which leads to final color value equal to `Cp` which was color of your Quad(white).

I think in this case you should set alpha of your quad to zero using `glColor4f(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f)`

Comment: now the texture is all black, even the non-trasparent pixels.

Comment: @Luca Obviously much time has passed since your comment, but maybe this will help the next guy. I had to get GL_MODULATE instead of GL_DECAL to get this to work. With GL_DECAL, it was black or white as you described, depending on the current color. I didn't have to enable GL_ALPHA either.